# How can I obtain Items on short ledges?

Tags: star-wars-dark-forces

In Star Wars Dark Forces, how can you get items located on short ledges?

I've recently acquired an old copy of the game and I'm playing it on DOS box.  From within the first level and the first 5 minutes of the game, I've spotted multiple items on short ledges, that are too tall to be steps, but are short enough to look like something you can jump on.

To my knowledge, jumping isn't possible.  How can I get items like the one below?

[image: How do I get that item?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jumping is very possible in **Dark Forces** and required to get through many parts of the game.  <kbd>X</kbd> is the default jump button on the keyboard.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  There's no controller config in the game and I didn't have a manual.  This is what I needed.

Comment: Download the manual from www.replacementdocs.com.